# When mysql query convert in to laravel query builder getting some error?

Tags: php, laravel

When I migrate below mysql query in to laravel query builder, I am getting error. Details are given below. Mysql queries are working correctly. Please check and correct me. How can I convert mysql query in to laravel query builder properly. Thanks

**error**

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row (SQL: select `c`.`firstname`, `c`.`lastname`, `p`.`order_id`, (SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_begin' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_begin, (SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_end' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_end, (SELECT ct.title FROM order_position_metas INNER JOIN course_types AS ct ON ct.id = VALUE WHERE NAME = 'course_type' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_type from `order_position_metas` inner join `order_positions` as `p` on `p`.`id` = `order_position_metas`.`order_position_id` inner join `order_passengers` as `pp` on `pp`.`order_id` = `p`.`order_id` inner join `customers` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `pp`.`customer_id` where `name` = school_id and `value` = 62 order by `course_begin` asc, `course_end` asc, `course_type` asc)
```

**Mysql Query**

This query is working

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, p.order_id,
                              (SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_begin' AND order_position_id = pm.order_position_id) AS course_begin,
                              (SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_end' AND order_position_id = pm.order_position_id) AS course_end,
                              (SELECT ct.title FROM order_position_metas INNER JOIN course_types ct ON ct.id = VALUE WHERE NAME = 'course_type' AND order_position_id = pm.order_position_id) AS course_type
                              FROM order_position_metas pm INNER JOIN order_positions p ON p.id = pm.order_position_id INNER JOIN order_passengers pp ON pp.order_id = p.order_id INNER JOIN customers c ON c.id = pp.customer_id
                              WHERE pm.name = 'school_id' AND pm.value = '".$request->schoolID."' ORDER BY course_begin ASC, course_end ASC, course_type ASC
```

**Laravel Querybuilder**

```
$nestedQueries = Orderpositionmeta::select('c.firstname', 'c.lastname', 'p.order_id', DB::raw("(SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_begin' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_begin"), DB::raw("(SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_end' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_end"), DB::raw("(SELECT ct.title FROM order_position_metas INNER JOIN course_types AS ct ON ct.id = VALUE WHERE NAME = 'course_type' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id) AS course_type"))
                    ->join('order_positions AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'order_position_metas.order_position_id')
                    ->join('order_passengers AS pp', 'pp.order_id', '=', 'p.order_id')
                    ->join('customers AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'pp.customer_id')
                    ->where('name', 'school_id')
                    ->where('value', $request->schoolID)
                    ->orderBy('course_begin')
                    ->orderBy('course_end')
                    ->orderBy('course_type')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: check the query which is build `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error shows that subquery returns more than one row. try subquery with LIMIT 1.

```
$nestedQueries = Orderpositionmeta::select('c.firstname', 'c.lastname', 'p.order_id', 
DB::raw("(SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_begin' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id LIMIT 1) AS course_begin"), 
DB::raw("(SELECT VALUE FROM order_position_metas WHERE NAME = 'course_end' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id LIMIT 1) AS course_end"), 
DB::raw("(SELECT ct.title FROM order_position_metas INNER JOIN course_types AS ct ON ct.id = VALUE WHERE NAME = 'course_type' AND order_position_id = order_position_metas.order_position_id LIMIT 1) AS course_type"))
->join('order_positions AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'order_position_metas.order_position_id')
->join('order_passengers AS pp', 'pp.order_id', '=', 'p.order_id')
->join('customers AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'pp.customer_id')
->where('name', 'school_id')
->where('value', $request->schoolID)
->orderBy('course_begin')
->orderBy('course_end')
->orderBy('course_type')
->get();
```